# Use Azure AD only for Authentication and not Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I've been messing with this for a few days now...

What I would like to do is Authenticate users with Azure AD, and when successful, automatically log them in using ASP.NET Identity for authorization. If they do not have an account I would like to create one automatically.

Essentially Azure AD is just confirming that they are a part of the organization, the ASP.NET Identity portion is it's own database where I can use the `[Authorize]` attribute to set up custom roles OUTSIDE of Azure AD.

This is my `ConfigureAuth()` method:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(IntranetApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                Authority = SettingsHelper.Authority,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey);
                        String signInUserId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));
                        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, SettingsHelper.AADGraphResourceId);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                        // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                        // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                        string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        // Suppress the exception if you don't want to see the error
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }

            });

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
        });
    }
```

Right now the ASP.NET Identity is taking over when I do a `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` which is okay, **I just need a way to check if the OpenID portion is authenticated** or not so I can put in my custom logic to automatically sign the user in.

Comment: I would say you shouldn't look for OpenID and should look for and use something like [Authorization in a web app using Azure AD groups & group claims](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/).

Comment: I actually just went through that article Yesterday, Azure AD Groups are clunky and not fluid like ASP.NET Identity Roles. I want Application Users to be able to change roles on the fly without having to consult IT to change it in Active Directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!

My biggest problem was attempting to use the OWIN middleware to do everything for me. The OpenID middleware is not needed for simple authentication to Azure AD. I essentially created a `OpenIdAuth` method in the Account controller which acts as my in-between to authenticate the user with Azure before they have access to the site.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult OpenIdAuth(string code)
{
    string clientId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; // Client ID found in the Azure AD Application
    string appKey = "111111111112222222222223333333333AAABBBCCC="; // Key generated in the Azure AD Appliction

    if (code != null)
    {
        string commonAuthority = "https://login.windows.net/<TENANT_URL>";  // Eg. https://login.windows.net/MyDevSite.onmicrosoft.com
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(commonAuthority);
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, "https://graph.windows.net");

        var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var signInManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();

        var user = UserManager.FindByName(authenticationResult.UserInfo.UniqueId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            signInManager.SignIn(user, false, false);
        }
        else
        {
            var newUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = authenticationResult.UserInfo.UniqueId, Email = authenticationResult.UserInfo.DisplayableId };
            var creationResult = UserManager.Create(newUser);

            if (creationResult.Succeeded)
            {
                user = UserManager.FindByName(newUser.UserName);
                signInManager.SignIn(user, false, false);
            }
            else
            {
                return new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
            }
        }

        return Redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        var url = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_URL>/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/Account/OpenIdAuth");
        return Redirect(url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

The awesome part is the `code` variable that will be passed by Microsoft when the user logs in successfully. (As documented [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/)) I used the same controller method and checked if it was null but technically two different controller methods can be used (Microsoft will redirect back to the url you specify for the `redirect_uri` parameter).

After I got the authorization code I can use the `AuthorizationContext` from the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` nuget package to call: `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode`. The last parameter is the Resource URI. I'm using the Graph Resource but you can use any other resource that you've given your app access to in the Azure Management Portal.

Finally my `ConfigureAuth` Method is back to the plain ol' ASP.NET Identity version:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(IntranetApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: the appKey you're referring to, is this a generated sescret in the Azure app?

Comment: @NiAu Yup! The secret comes from when you create a new App Registration in Azure AD